# How to execute batch class more than once in a test method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

While testing a `Batchable` class in Salesforce, we wrap the execution with `Test.startTest` and `Test.stopTest` to make sure the batch class completes before asserting the results:

```
Test.startTest();
SuperMachoBatch b = new SuperMachoBatch();
Database.executeBatch(b);   
Test.stopTest();

// verify results and do some stuff that will affect the execution results of the next run...

Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(b);   
Test.stopTest();

// verify results
```

However, there are times when we need to run the batch class more than once in a single test method. The problem is, one can only call `startTest` and `endTest` once within a test method.

One option we considered is to simulate the results of the first call, since we already have test coverage that tests the expected results of the first call. However, I thought I'd raise the question to the community first before going down this road.

Are there other options available to start and stop a batch class multiple times in the context a single test method?

Comment: Refer [Testing multiple asynchronous processes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110700/testing-multiple-asynchronous-processes) I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One option we considered is to simulate the results of the first call, since we already have test coverage that tests the expected results of the first call.

Exactly this. You should set up your data as if the first batch had already run instead of running it to simulate its effects.

This sort of setup may be where having a well organized **[`Service Layer`](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_sl)** can be useful, as your batch `execute` method would just call service methods which you can then use elsewhere, including tests.

```
public class SuperMachoBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    ...
    public void execute(Datbase.BatchableContext context, List<MyObject__c> records)
    {
        MyObjectService.doStuff(records);
        MyObjectService.doOtherStuff(records);
    }
    ...
}

@IsTest
class OtherBatchTests
{
    @TestSetup
    static void setup()
    {
        List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject__c>();
        // populate and insert
        MyObjectService.doStuff(records);
        MyObjectService.doOtherStuff(records);
    }
    static testmethod void testOtherBatch()
    {
        Test.startTest();
            Database.executeBatch(new OtherBatch());
        Test.stopTest();
        // assert on effects
    }
    // other tests?
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course! Why didn't I think of that? :)

Comment: I actually ended up with a very similar architecture so I can just call `run()` in my tests and `runAsync()` in my real world code - the latter automatically running a batch with the correct settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you find you need to execute the batch multiple times in your test your first question should be:

> Can I break this up into different test methods.

or

> Am I testing distinct logic branches / outcomes, if so use multiple test methods

In those cases where you need to actually test something but need one batch to run and then another batch to run you can do the following:

in your test to execute the batches used to set up the batch you are testing:

```
FirstBatch b = New FirstBatch();
sObject[] records = //Query for the records just like your start method would do
b.execute(null, records);
```

if the start returns an iterable then you can simply

```
FirstBatch b = New FirstBatch();
b.execute(null, b.start());
```

Repeat with additional setup batches.

Then when you get to the batch you actually want to test do it the normal way using the `test.StartTest` and `database.ExecuteBatch`

If the batches are unrelated and just need to have both run then you can simple execute both batches inside the same start and stop and they will both run after the `test.stoptest`

Comment: Adrian's answer is better although it may require a rewrite of code. If you cannot rewrite to add the service layer the above may help....

Comment: Ha, right. Manually execute. Definitely a good quick&dirty route if you need one.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate another variable to execute batch I.e.

```
Test.startTest();
SuperMachoBatch b = new SuperMachoBatch();
SuperMachoBatch c = new SuperMachoBatch();
Database.executeBatch(b);
Database.executeBatch(c);

Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: This will not work if you need to have at least two batches run from just one batch job.