# How is an individual batch called vs. the batch that it's part of?

Tags: batch

So - I was always confused about the batch terminology. You can call `Database.executeBatch` to - you guessed it - execute a batch. But then again this "batch" also consists of a couple of batches. Does it make sense to call both the parts and the whole a batch? I find that incredibly confusing. How should we refer to both?

EDIT:
To clarify this a bit more - my question is how we refer to this in our everyday life. I personally tend to call it batch job with N batches but that's not what I use throughout the day - I just call both of them batches. Which also comes from the fact that in Apex I refer to the whole batch job as batch. Since language-wise a batch is a collection of things this is actually true for both. So how can we communicate this without ambiguity, whether we're speaking with a user or a developer?

And this guy here is as confused as I am: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BL8SIAW

The confusion is real - just look how they are referred to in this question: [How to execute batch class more than once in a test method?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171760/how-to-execute-batch-class-more-than-once-in-a-test-method)

Comment: The whole Operation is called batch, and each iteration is called as chunks.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Can you cite some sources for this? Or is it just personal preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Database.executeBatch()`, it does not execute a batch, rather it executes a `batch class`. Within batch class, it splits the data into `chunks` depending on the `batch size` provided. And the chunk of records which are created after split is called as `batch` (i.e. each chunk is called as batch). You can specify the `number of records` which should be processed in single batch by providing the `batch size` (**default is 200 and maximum is 2000**). And that chunk (batch) of records are passed one by one (i.e. each chunk at a time) to `execute` method to perform the necessary operations.

You can refer [Asynchronous Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch) trailhead module for more information.

Comment: I clarified my question a bit as I think that most of the confusion comes from developers having their batches named batch, not job. I guess I'll just go with batch job and batch in the meantime